# save uiimageview to coredata as binary data swift (5)

Tags: core-data, imageview, appdelegate, binary-data, swift5

I am trying to save a imageview as a image to binary data in core data. My code is not working. It has a compile error. In View controller it is not regisitering cdHandler. All i want to do is save the the imaveview as binary data in a core data model.I have 2 classes a app delegate and a view controller.

CLASS VIEW CONTROLLER

```
    import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
var canVasView = UIImageView()
@objc func hhh() {
    let photo = self.canVasView.image
    let data = photo!.pngData()

    if cdHandler.saveObject(pic:  data!){
    }
}
}
```

APP DELEGATE

```
  import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


     lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
         /*
          The persistent container for the application. This implementation
          creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
          application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
          error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
          */
         let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
         container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
             if let error = error as NSError? {
                 // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                 // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
class cdHandler: NSObject {

    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appdeleagetzz = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appdeleagetzz.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    class func saveObject(pic: Data, userName: String) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)
        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        managedObject.setValue(pic, forKey:"pic")
        managedObject.setValue(userName, forKey:"userName")
        do {
            try context.save()
            return true

        } catch {
            return false

        }
    }
    class func deletObject(user: User) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        context.delete(user)

        do {
            try context.save()
            return true
        } catch {
            return false

        }
    }

    class func fetchObject() -> [User]? {

        do {
            let context = getContext()
            return try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            return [User]()
        }
    }

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your quesion to add the text of the *compile error* which you are getting.  Copy from the Issue navigator and paste.

Comment: @JerryKrinock I added some pictures.

Comment: OK, well, you did it the hard way :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message, *Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member named 'persistentContainer', explains the problem.  Indeed, when I look at the code for your `AppDelegate` class, I can confirm that it has no member named 'persistentContainer'.  (If I am reading it correctly, the last two lines in the file are closing curly brackets.  The first one closes your `cdHandler` nested class, and the second one closes your `AppDelegate` class.)

Do the following exercise.  In Xcode, click in the menu: *File* > *New Project* and select *iOS*, *Application* and *Single View App*.  Name your new project *Junk*.  Switch on the *Core Data* checkbox.  Click button *Create*.  After it is done, look at the AppDelegate.swift which Xcode created, and in the `AppDelegate` class, you see it contains 8 functions (`func`).  The 7th one is `lazy var persistentContainer`.  Aha!  The compiler is telling you that *you probably should not have deleted those 8 functions, `persistentContainer` in particular*.

You should copy that `persistentContainer` func from that *Junk* project into your `AppDelegate` class in your real project.  Or, to head off future trouble, consider copying most of the other 7 funcs also.  As you can see, most of them don't do anything except provide comments with explanations that are useful for beginners.  After you are done copying, close the *Junk* project.  (I overwrite my *Junk* project with a new *Junk* project several times in a typical week, especially when answering StackOverflow questions.)

That should fix this particular error and answer this question.  Onward to the next issue.  :)

#### Response to comment that you still get *the error with cdHandler*

Having nothing else to go on, I presume that *the error* that you are referring to is the compiler error still in your screenshot.  In other words, you are saying that adding the `persistentContainer` definition did not make it any better.

Well, it works for me.  Please replace all of the code in your *AppDelegate.swift* class with the following, build and run it…

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        AppDelegate.cdHandler.testGetContext()
        return true
    }

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Junk")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    class cdHandler: NSObject {

        private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
            let appdeleagetzz = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            return appdeleagetzz.persistentContainer.viewContext
        }

        class func testGetContext() {
            let context = getContext()
            print("getContext() succeeded, got \(context)")
        }

        class func saveObject(pic: Data, userName: String) -> Bool {
            let context = getContext()
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: context)
            let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
            managedObject.setValue(pic, forKey:"pic")
            managedObject.setValue(userName, forKey:"userName")
            do {
                try context.save()
                return true

            } catch {
                return false

            }
        }
        class func deletObject(user: NSManagedObject) -> Bool {
            let context = getContext()
            context.delete(user)

            do {
                try context.save()
                return true
            } catch {
                return false

            }
        }

    }
}
```

You see that compiles with no errors.  Also, it runs and the AppDelegate.cdhandler.getContext() method works.  As you can see, in `AppDelegate.application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:), I have added a call to a new method which I defined later,`AppDelegate.cdHandler.testGetContext()`.  It works perfectly.

Are you getting a different error now?  If so, you need to specify whether it is a Build or Run error.  In either case, copy and paste the text of the  error into your question, and tell us where it occurs.

Comment: I added persistent container but the error with cd handler is still there that is the only remaining. I edited my question above.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the above comment.

Comment: The problem with chandler is still happening. This is a link to my project via dropbox can you take a look https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubo1n0pd6f5m2sw/draw%20copy.zip?dl=0. Thanks. Your the man.